# One-liner shortcut for reassigning a list to an array

Tags: c++, c++17

How to elegantly simplify (or eliminate) the `for loops` in the code below, using C++17 features ?

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
        typedef struct ethernet_frame
        {
            unsigned char   dst[6]; 
            unsigned char   src[6]; 
            unsigned short  proto;
        } ethernet_frame, *ethernet_frame_ptr;
#pragma pack(pop)

        int i;
        ethernet_frame eFrame = { {00,00,00,00,00,00}, {42, 54, 33, 67, 14, 88}, 0x800 };
        ProcessFrame(&eFrame); //A library function expecting an address of an ethernet_frame with its strict bit layout

        i = 0;
        for (unsigned char c : { 36, 84, 23, 77, 35, 11 }) eFrame.dst[i++] = c;
        ProcessFrame(&eFrame);

        i = 0;
        for (unsigned char c : { 65, 23, 74, 82, 20, 94 }) eFrame.dst[i++] = c;
        ProcessFrame(&eFrame);

        i = 0;
        for (unsigned char c : { 47, 22, 86, 45, 33, 38 }) eFrame.dst[i++] = c;
        ProcessFrame(&eFrame);

        // etc...
```

Reassignments like `eFrame.Dst = { 47, 22, 86, 45, 33, 38 }` would be neat ...but they are illegal :(

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::array`?

Comment: @ Algirdas: Because I cannot be certain how `std::array<unsigned char, 6>` would be arranged in memory.  An `Ethernet Frame` must have a very specific bit layout.

Comment: "_Because I cannot be certain how `std::array<unsigned char, 6>` would be arranged in memory._" Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ Algirdas: Because an `Ethernet Frame` must have a very specific bit layout for transmission over the network.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType

Comment: 1) One can obtain the pointer to the underlying buffer via `std::array::data`. So, unless you are doing something with the whole structure (not shown in your [mre]), the not knowing of memory layout, shouldn't be a problem. 2) The thing is: arrays in C++ are not assignable. You either use a wrapper, that allows said functionality, or do what you do.

Comment: "*One can obtain the pointer to the underlying buffer via* `std::array::data`".  Is this data guaranteed to be packed as by `#pragma pack(1)` ?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot conclude from it, that padding is not added.  If it is, then it will destroy the layout of the `Ethernet Frame`

Comment: "_This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member._"

Comment: "*...as its only non-static data member*".  What about its static members?

Comment: "_What about its static members?_" Why do those matter? `static` members aren't allocated in the same manner, or in the same block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you couldn't change `struct ethernet_frame` to use `std::array`, then there are still several one-liners you could use to copy data, albeit less safely. First, using good old `memcpy()`:

```
#include <cstring>
...
memcpy(eFrame.dst, std::array<unsigned char, 6>{36, 84, 23, 77, 35, 11}.begin(), std::size(eFrame.dst));
```

Or using `std::copy_n()`:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::copy_n(std::array<unsigned char, 6>{36, 84, 23, 77, 35, 11}.begin(), std::size(eFrame.dst), eFrame.dst);
```

With the [Ranges TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges#Algorithms), you can avoid having to specify the size of the data you want to copy:

```
#include <experimental/ranges/algorithm>
...
std::experimental::ranges::copy(std::array<unsigned char, 6>{36, 84, 23, 77, 35, 11}, eFrame.dst);
```

Also, if there is no one-liner for something you want to use more than once, then you can of course always write a function yourself that turns the problem into a one-liner.

Comment: Can `std::copy` be used, too ?

Comment: No, `std::copy` needs both a start and an end iterator, it's not possible to do this with a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a one-liner, but a simple function that uses C++17 fold expressions:

```
template<typename... Ts, typename T>
void set_elements(T (&arr)[sizeof...(Ts)], Ts... values) {
    auto ptr = arr;
    ((*ptr++ = values), ...);
}
```

and then:

```
set_elements(eFrame.dst, 36, 84, 23, 77, 35, 11);
```

Comment: Using the comma operator and side effects... it's horrible and beautifully simple at the same time :)